# How to scrape the #text xml using selenium webdriver python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape this website [Century Office Products, Inc](https://www.corporationwiki.com/New-Jersey/Middlesex/century-office-products-inc/53844156.aspx) and I am unable to scrape this text:

```
Century Office Products, Inc. industry is listed as Ret Misc Merchandise
```

as the tag in which it is contained is #text. Following is the code I have tried:

```
driver.get('https://www.corporationwiki.com/New-Jersey/Middlesex/century-office-products-inc/53844156.aspx')
text = [k.text for k in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='card']//div[@class='card-body']//h2//following::p[2]")]
```

Comment: So, you are willing to parse that portion of text from that website which you have mentioned within the double quotes in your description and nothing else, right?

Comment: @SIM Yes,other things I am able to scrap .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the text **Century Office Products, Inc.** using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you need to use *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *Xpath*:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://www.corporationwiki.com/New-Jersey/Middlesex/century-office-products-inc/53844156.aspx")
    print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h1[@itemprop='legalName']")))).strip())
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    Century Office Products, Inc.
    ```

Answer (score 2):

Using xpath:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

link = "https://www.corporationwiki.com/New-Jersey/Middlesex/century-office-products-inc/53844156.aspx"

r = requests.get(link, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
tree = fromstring(r.text)
elem = tree.xpath("//*[@class='card-body']/div/following::text()")[0].strip()
print(elem)
```

using css selector:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.corporationwiki.com/New-Jersey/Middlesex/century-office-products-inc/53844156.aspx"

r = requests.get(link, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
elem = soup.select_one("[class='card-body'] > div").next_sibling.strip()
print(elem)
```

They both produce the same output:

```
Century Office Products, Inc. industry is listed as Ret Misc Merchandise.
```